# ITelemetryProcessor behavior when deployed to AppService

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have created a custom telemetry processor which is adding customer properties to the telemetry items. When running locally, I don’t see any issue and I am seeing the properties being added(both in release and debug mode) and logged to the AppInsights.

When deployed to app service, I am seeing the logs, but the properties being added by the telemetry processor are missing.

I am using .Net Core 2.1 and the Application insights NuGet version  is 2.3.0.  Is there a way to debug why this is happening? Also is anyone aware if this is a known issue?

Comment: How are you registering our custom processor?

Comment: @PeterBons :       
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services
                .AddMemoryCache()
                .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<TelemetryLogger>()
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share your code which adds application insights and the telemetry processor? It should be something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyFirstCustomTelemetryProcessor>();

    // If you have more processors:
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MySecondCustomTelemetryProcessor>();

    // ...
}
```

Can you try to print the list of TelemetryProcessors registered with the TelemetryConfiguration instance? You can constructor inject `TelemetryConfiguration` to a controller class, and print out the list. Something like shown below.

```
string tpList;

        public ValuesController(TelemetryConfiguration tc)
        {
            var tps = tc.TelemetryProcessors;
            foreach(var tp in tps)
            {
               var s = tp.GetType().ToString();
                tpList += s;
            }

        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", tpList };
        }
```

This should confirm if the TelemetryProcessor is even in the config.

Also, when you say works local - do you mean when running from Visual Studio? VS alters behavior, so can try to run locally outside of VS, and see if it reproes.

Comment: I tried  it outside VS by deploying it to IIS. I see that the telemetry processor is part of the configuration(using above method). I have created a sample app for you(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhaCKWQA3MPkop5xnI6U511Vi3bs7g) . With the above said method, i face 2 issues now, 1. as described in the description above. 2. ILogger.Log doesnt log to applicaiton insights.

Comment: I just tried the sample app and it works fine for me. i.e I deployed the app to local folder, ran it using dotnet run TestApp.dll, fired a request to http://localhost:5000/api/values, and the Request telemetry collected by AI SDK has ":{"X-Correlation-Id":"Not Found"," - proving that the TelemetryProcessor has run.

Comment: To get Ilogger.Log you need to enable it. Modify Configure method to take `ILoggerFactory loggerFactory` as an argument, and add the following line `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Warning);`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Logging  - This shows full example.

Comment: Thanks Cijo. That helped. Now i am seeing the info added in app insights. Probably you could include your last comment also as part of the answer. ILogger.Log was logging the events to app insights as we have added the following 2 lines in the startup. _loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(services.BuildServiceProvider());AddSingleton(_loggerFactory)

Comment: Glad to know logger issue is solved. What about the TelemetryProcessor one?

Comment: Yes. Both were resolved post making the changes to the configuration